# WCF with HTTPS on Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, https

I have set up a web role that hosts two endpoints (one HTTP and the other HTTPS). Both endpoints are pointing to the same service `Main.svc` which is configured to be RESTful. This is my configuration (showing only the HTTPS one as it's the one giving me problem):

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AthenaBehaviorConfigHttps" name="Athena.LEC.Service.Main">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AthenaBehaviorEndpointConfig"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Athena.LEC.Service.IMain" />
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBasic" name="basicHttpSecure" contract="Athena.LEC.Service.IMain" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Behavior config:

```
    <behavior name="AthenaBehaviorConfigHttps">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="" httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
```

Basic http binding:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecureBasic">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

On the Azure web role configuration:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
      <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="HttpsEndpoint" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpEndpoint" protocol="http" port="7902" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsEndpoint" protocol="https" port="7955" />
</Endpoints>
```

On HTTP I have verified that the restful call was successful. However, on port 7955 (configured as Https), when I use my browser to make a call it just resulted in an empty page (normally the JSON result will be returned). Is this normal? Or am I configuring something wrongly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your binding to use basicHttp*s*Binding instead.  I show how to secure WCF endpoints for http and tcp in [this post](http://rickrainey.com/2013/09/18/securing-a-wcf-service-in-an-azure-web-role-with-http-tcp-endpoints-2/).  So, you can use it as a reference to check against your solution.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I've followed your post's examples but has reached at the same result. I am not sure if it's the way I'm testing the service endpoint that is incorrect, I am using a browser to simulate the https get call, should I create a client and perform the test instead? I also read somewhere that https get will not work on local emulator, not sure if that's true.

Comment: I would recommend you use Fiddler instead as your client to test with.  You will be able to do more than just GET.  You will also see the full response.  It could be you're getting the response you expect but the browser is just not rendering it correctly (or at all).

Comment: Thanks, your blog post guided me towards the correct direction. I've been using Fiddler and all was working fine.